# Why does my Web API give a 301 response?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I have the AngularJS code below which calls the Web API URL:

http://www.stevegaines.info/api/Certifications

When I enter this URL in my browser I see good data, but when I run my AngularJS code I see nothing.  So I go into developer tools and under Network the Request looks right, but the Response is 301 Moved Permanently.  2 days ago I switched Web Hosts and then I switched back.  Could that be the reason?  It's been over 24 hours since I updated my DNS.

```js
        var oApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

        oApp.controller("certificationsCtrl", function ($scope, $http)
        {
            $scope.Certifications = {};
            var url1 = "http://www.stevegaines.info/api/Certifications";

            $http.get(url1)
                .success(function (response)
                {
                    console.log("Data: " + response.data);
                    $scope.Certifications = response.data;
                });
        });
```

Comment: Because you have a 301 Redirect to your "naked domain" (from "www" to without "www")  - perhaps a canonical rule? So call your API without the "www"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was CORS - Cross origin resource sharing.  In other words, the call was from a different domain and for that to work I need to enable CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Your website appears to automatically redirect from www to the non-www version which could be what you are seeing when you request that URL. Most browsers handle this automatically though and follow the redirect even when using AJAX or a framework.

You can try it without the www in the code and then using the debug tools you can see what is returned. Check the Response tab or Content tab so see what is returned OR if you still get a 301 check the Location header that is returned and that might make things clearer.

Comment: Scottie (and EdSF): Thanks.  I'm weak in network issues.  Your tip helped.  I took out the www. and it now gives me a 500 Internal Server Error.  The thing is yesterday I was having the 500 error and a reader suggested I add www.  So I did and it worked.  But today things have moved around and now this.  AngularJS seems really cool, but very delicate.  I've been fighting with this for about 5 days.  It just shouldn't be this complicated.

Comment: I don't have much experience with AngularJS but i thought it was a client side JavaScript framework. A 500 error is a server side HTTP response code which can be caused by lots of things and could even be due to a change of host. To diagnose a 500 error you need to check server side logs such as Apache or PHP.

Comment: Scottie, I've debugged some more and it looks like it's not getting the JSON data it wants.  I'll try re-working the Web API and the AngularJS settings.  There's only about 500 combinations of settings left.  I may get it right before I'm eligible for Social Security.